# Exploring $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$: what does it mean to have the union of a countably infinite set with $\infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

While studying advanced complex analysis, I have finally encountered the extended complex numbers. The extended complex numbers is defined as the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ together with {$\infty$} such that $\mathbb{C} \cup${$\infty$}; which is also defined as the Riemann sphere. Where addition and multiplication are defined as for $z \in \mathbb{C}$: $$z + \infty = \infty$$ $$z \bullet \infty = \infty.$$ As I studied these operations on the set $\mathbb{C} \cup${$\infty$}, regrettably, I began to ask questions about the intuition of these operations. If infinity is not a number, how is it that $1 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $1+ \infty = \infty$ if there are different sizes of infinity? Even worse, what does it mean to union an uncountably infinite set $\mathbb{C}$ with infinity?

I understand the scope of this question is quite large, however any response (intuitive or not) will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Arithmetic can only be extended in a limited fashion to the Riemann sphere. The big deal is that it is now compact. But to get compactness, the notion of open sets needs to be extended to include the new point ('$\infty'$). The new point is **not** a number, but for selected operations we can treat is as 'sort of' a number.

Comment: I think the geometrical point of view is the most intuitive.  Using stereographic projection, you map $\mathbb C$ to a sphere with its north pole missing.  That missing point is what you label as $\infty$.  You might say it's not really "infinity": it's a very concrete object, a point on a sphere.  Then you see how the various operations can be extended to this new point.

Comment: @Robert Israel - that makes the most sense to me. If time in your schedule permits, please feel free to make your comment into an answer. I would love to explore that explanation more. If not, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Made into an answer at OP's request]

I think the geometrical point of view is the most intuitive. Using stereographic projection, you map $\mathbb C$ to a sphere with its north pole missing. That missing point is what you label as $\infty$. You might say it's not really "infinity": it's a very concrete object, a point on a sphere. Then you see how the various operations can be extended to this new point.